# Mocha 'before each hook' error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

**I have the following message, just before a failing test**

Below is my piece of code

```
before(function(done) {
  function afterListening() {
    customFormats(ZSchema);
    done();
  }

  if (app.server.listening) return afterListening();

  app.on('listening', afterListening);
});

describe('/a1/{exampleID}', function() {
  describe('get', function() {
    it('should respond with 200 Return an array of shelter...', function(done) {
      /*eslint-disable*/
      var schema = {
        "type": [
          "object",
          "null"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "meta": {
            "type": [
              "object",
              "null"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "resource": {
                "type": [
                  "string",
                  "null"
                ],
                "description": "fully qualified URL call"
              },
              "version": {
                "type": [
                  "string",
                  "null"
                ],
                "description": "version of API being called"
              },
              "response": {
                "type": [
                  "integer",
                  "null"
                ],
                "format": "int32",
                "description": "status code"
              },
            "required": [
              "version",
              "resource"
            ]
          } 
        }
      };

      /*eslint-enable*/
      api.get('/a1/example/64442')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) return done(err);

        validator.validate(res.body, schema).should.be.true;
        done();
      });
    });
});
});
```

**Error**
1) example "before each" hook:
     Error: timeout of 200ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being 
      called in this test.
      at null. (lib/runnable.js:170:19)

*This error came only when I run the test case on my machine.If I run the same test case in another machine the test case is passing. why it happens.It's weird to see like this.*

Any help, please!!

Comment: We will need to see your code with a little more detail of the difference between the two machines.

Answer (score 1):

You generally receive timeout error, when you are not returning a promise as expected.

Done is the older implementation of the same, but no longer required. If you are using a recent version of Mocha, you should be able to just return the promise instead of calling Done().

Here are details on [mocha-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-as-promised) - which was integrated with default Mocha, since version 1.18.0.

Example of how you should return a promise:

```
it("should be fulfilled with 5", function () {
  return promise.should.become(5);
});
```

In case of beforeeach - implementation should look like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
 const {col1, comments} = mongoose.connection.collections;

 return col1.drop(() => {
    // Do something after collection is dropped
 });
});
```

Notice return for the action taken within beforeeach.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please share your beforeEach with us so we can help?

Without looking, it might be because your connection to whatever thing you're connecting to isn't responding on time or isn't responding at all.

Might wanna check your connection to places where your unit tests are connecting (chances are it's the database, because it's in `beforeEach()` and `beforeEach()` doesn't require a `done()` to be called inside it.

Increase your timeout to something like 10 seconds or such. If you don't get database errors then, your connection is slow. If you still get timeout errors even at 10 seconds, you might have no connection at all.